# Multiple UI-Views not working as expected

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am trying to use multiple UI-views in my AngularJS app and it is not working as expected. The app is a dashboard.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
index.html
app/
    app.js
    dashboard/
        dashboard.html
        dashboard.js
        partials/
            business.html
            items.html
            orders.html
            sales.html
    login/
        login.html
        login.js
```

The problem that I am having is that my index.html file has the following line of code:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

The above line enables my application to show the login.html page and dashboard.html page. Now I want to be able to have partial views in my dashboard.html page and so I have also put the same line of code

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

in order to be able to embed partial views in my dashboard page. Instead of embedding though, the page instead just redirects. So for example if I am in my dashboard.html and click on a navigation item such as 'business', I am redirected to partials/business.html instead of the content being embedded.

1) Can I have multiple ui-views embedded within each other?
2) Am I correctly embedding the partial views?

I have scoured the internet but cannot find a solution. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely have multiple embedded views.

Check out these AngularJS UI-Router tutorials: [Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) and [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

Let me know if you still have issues after looking them over.

Comment: I bumped to the same problem some weeks ago and my head is still in pain. What I realized is that there's no a decent solution, unless you have a well defined set of states for which the nested views can be mapped. If you need (like me) something dynamic (such as WPF), simply there's nothing ready and you have to create something by yourself (and that's another pain)

Comment: If any given module is complex enough, I tend to prefer splitting it into smaller constituent modules -- each accessible through a child state (or named view, depending) -- and letting the submodules handle their own internal routing. It seems complicated at first but becomes old hat pretty quickly. But I definitely hear you, it would be nice if there were some clean solution that works right out of the box.

Comment: My web (so AngularJS) experience is still short (some months), but I have a strong knowledge of the WPF/.Net framework, which is damn awesome and allows a very flexible yet almost perfect component reuse. However, that's for desktop, and I really miss something similar for the web. At the moment, for my Angular SPA app, I solved with a custom templating system, which does not use the ng-view technique, nor the state routing. As soon it'll be ready, I share the code.

Comment: SamuelMS, I cannot upvote your comment but it worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a ui-view inside another ui-view. I have implemented it in the following manner and its pretty straight forward.

Inside index.html I have code:

```
      <div ui-view=""></div>
```

Then inside user.html I have code

```
     <div ui-view=""></div>
```

And I have defined a config for displaying my views as

```
     .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {



     var users = {
        //Name must be in format Parent.Child
        name: 'users',
        url: '/user',
        templateUrl: 'users/user.html',
        controller: 'usersHandler',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Welcome to Users'
        },

    },

    createUsers = {
        name: 'users.createUsers',
        url: '/createUser',
        templateUrl: 'users/createUser.html',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Create Users'
        }
    },
    listUsers = {
        name: 'users.listUsers',
        url: '/listUsers',
        templateUrl: 'users/userLists.html',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Users listing'
        }
    },

    getUserDealer = {
        name: 'users.getUserDealer',
        url: '/getUserDealer',
        templateUrl: 'users/getUserDealer.html',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Users dealer listing'
        }
    },

    editUser = {
        name: 'users.editUser',
        url: '/editUser',
        templateUrl: 'users/editUser.html',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Edit User'
        }
    };
    //Similarly define all the combination you want to separate

   //add routes to stateProvider
    $stateProvider
        .state('users', users)
        .state('users.createUsers', createUsers)
        .state('users.listUsers', listUsers)
        .state('users.getUserDealer', getUserDealer)
        .state('users.editUser', editUser);

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/user/listUsers');

        });
```

Whats happening is this that user.html is my parent file which is loaded inside index.html and editUser.html, getUserDealer.html and userLists.html etc are its children which I load within user.html using ui-view.

And I provide the links for nested pages as:

```
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#/user/createUser">NEW USER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/user/listUsers">GET USER</a></li>
       </ul>
```

This can be extended to additional parents and their children as per the need.
Hope it helps!!